# In a Beamer presentation, is it possible to cancel highlighting for something inside \alert?

Tags: beamer, highlighting

I have a macro, which in simplified form looks like this:

```latex
\newcommand{\func}[2]{#1\left(#2\right)}
```

Example of its application:

```latex
\func{f}{x^2}
```

On a beamer overlay, I want to highlight the function name (argument 1) *and the accompanying parentheses*, but *not* the function argument (argument 2).

Because of the macro and the matching pair of `\left` and `\right`, it is not possible to achieve this with two `\alert`'s. Without the macro and sized parentheses, it could be achieved like this:

```latex
\alert{f(}x^2\alert{)}
```

**What I would like to be able to do is this**:

```latex
\alert{\func{f}{\noalert{x^2}}}
```

Is it possible, somehow, to define **`\noalert`**, or does it already exist?
(I checked the Beamer manual, and searched for an answer, to no avail.)

Sure, I could just highlight the function name only, and not the parentheses:

```latex
\func{\alert{f}}{x^2}
```

But my situation is more complex, and this example is a simplification
(my situation involves more complex 'parentheses').
There probably are other situations with a similar demand.

Comment: Could you please make a complete compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and add it to your question?

Comment: Probably you could use something like the following: `\newcommand{\noalert}[1]{{\color{normal text.fg}#1}}`?

Comment: Since I don't know how to make it work, I cannot provide an example, but I can add the framework in which to put a solution. How complete should it be? Including `documentclass` and `usepackage`?

Comment: @leandriis That definition of `\noalert` works. Thanks. I will also need to make it overlay aware. I will submit it as a feature request for Beamer.

Comment: Including overlay awareness: `\newcommand<>{\noalert}[1]{{\color#2{normal text.fg}#1}}`.

Comment: @leandriis Would you like to post an answer?